# "expect" to continue test even after failing

Tags: angularjs, testing, protractor

I'm still a beginner in Protractor so forgive me if it is not the most optimized code. Although any advice and help are appreciated.

```
var orderno =["100788743","100788148","100788087","100000000","100786703"];
        for (var i = 0; i < orderno.length; i++) {
            (function(Loop) {
                element(by.css('[autoid="_is_3"]')).sendKeys(orderno[i]);
                browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.ENTER).perform();
                expect(element(by.cssContainingText("span.Class", "Store A")).waitReady()).toBeTruthy();
                element(by.cssContainingText("span.Class", "Store A")).isDisplayed().then(function(pickfail) {
                    if (pickfail) {
                        element(by.css('[class="highlight"]')).getText().then(function(text) {
                            console.log(text + "-" + "Pass");
                        });
                    } else {
                        console.log("Order Number: Missing");
                    }
                });
                element(by.css('[autoid="_is_3"]')).clear();
            })([i]);
        };
```

*waitReady is there to wait for the element to come up but I believe it its trying to find it but couldn't so it timesout.

I've created a test where I could input a value in a textbox which would search and check if it exists or not. If it does, it passes but if it doesn't, then fails. But want the loop to continue even if it fails to see if the other remaining items exist.

I think expect would fail when it couldn't find the value thus stopping the whole test. Is there another way to check and continue the whole checking?

Comment: Add these as promises and then resolve them with `Promise.all`, then check if list contains all true's, if not if failed.

Comment: You have to use `forEach()` loop for these scenarios, it accepts a function which would be called for each of the elements regardless if it fails or not. and the `expect` here is redundant as you are using `isDisplayed()` for that

Comment: @RamPasala I've changed it to forEach() and it worked out well thanks. I've changed the expect to just browser.sleep(); Having just isDisplayed() would cause it to fail because it wasn't loading on time. But even if I let it sleep, when it couldn't find the value it is looking for, it'll still fail and stop the whole test.

Comment: In that case you could use `browser.wait(element(by.cssContainingText("span.Class", "Store A")).isDisplayed(),5000)` or use Protractor's Expected Conditions to wait for the `isDisplayed()` promise to be fulfilled else you could catch that promise error which will not let it fail!